# Display multiple validation errors for Mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have this schema:

```
var userSchema = Schema(
    {name : {
        type: String
    }
});

userSchema.path('name').validate(function(value) {
    return value.length > 4;
}, 'Name is too short');

userSchema.path('name').validate(function(value) {
    return hasNoNumbers(value);
}, 'Name cannot have numbers');

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Then I create a model like this and run the validate function:

```
var newUser = new User({name: '1da'});

newUser.validate(function(err) {
    console.log(err.errors.name);
})
```

This only logs the first error message 'Name is too short'. However, the name property fails both validation requirements. Is there a way to display both error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this feature isn't implemented in v3 of mongoose.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/1214#issuecomment-15746525

When v4 become stable, I'll give it a try again.

Until then, this module seems to solve this issue:

https://github.com/szdc/mongoose-validate-all